# Static and dynamic behaviour of a sensor

Tags: sensor, control-system, transfer-function

On a slide, i read that i can model the static behaviour of a sensor as:

[image]

whereas it's dynamic behaviour as:

[image]

Is correct to say that the static behaviour is the steady-state behaviour, while the dynamic behaviour represents the transient?
Thanks

Comment: Didn't you ask pretty much the same question some 16 hrs ago? Anyway, no, I don't think that's accurate; dynamic behaviour describes dynamic behaviour, not just transients.

Answer (score 1):

> the dynamic behaviour represents the transient?

No, the dynamic behavior also describes the response to a continuously varying input, not just transient behavior (i.e. response to a momentary input). You can also extract the \$c_1\$ term of the static behavior (it's the same as \$K_1\$) from the dynamic behavior, but not the offset (\$c_0\$).

Comment: So in simple terms, the static behavior is the steady state behavior, whereas the dynamic behavior comprises both steady state and transient , right ?

Comment: The static behavior is the DC steady state response. The sinusoidal or AC steady state response is part of the dynamic behavior.

Comment: @themagiciant95 so, no, not quite right. There's more than steady state and transient.